# Vue | define reactive property in plugin

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

Trying to build my own form validation plugin (it's for learning purposes - so I don't use existing libraries).

So I created the following mixin:

```
export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    if (! this.$vnode || /^(keep-alive|transition|transition-group)$/.test(this.$vnode.tag)) {
      return;
    }

    // create
    this.$validator = new Instance();

    // define computed
    if (! this.$options.computed) {
      this.$options.computed = {};
    }

    this.$options.computed['errors'] = function() {
      return this.$validator.errors;
    };
  }
}
```

And loaded the mixin from the component (cause I don't want to see this anywhere):

```
export default {
    name: "SignIn",
    components: {
      AppLayout,
      TextField,
      HelperText,
      Button
    },
    mixins: [ValidateMixin]
  }
```

Anyway, anytime input has changed - there is an event which tests the value and controls my errors bag:

```
export default class {

  constructor() {
    this.items = {};
  }

  first(name) {
    if (name in this.items) {
      return this.items[name][0];
    }

    return false;
  }

  add(name, errors) {
    this.items[name] = errors;
  }

  remove(name) {
    delete this.items[name];
  }

  has(name) {
    return name in this.items;
  }

  all() {
    return this.items;
  }

}
```

I've bind HTML element (`:invalid="errors.has('email')"`), and with the devtools I can see the errors bag changing - but the binding is just doesn't work. The invalid property remains `false` no matter what I'm doing.

I do understand that in order to create reactive property, I've to handle this with getters/setters, but I'm a bit stuck with it.

Comment: You need to use `Vue.set(object_already_observed(this for instance), key, value)` to ensure Vue can watch it.

Comment: I see you're adding properties to `items`, which is an object. See [Object Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but doesn't seem like it help. I'm printing the errors while submitting the form and can see that it changed, but the HTML binding doesn't work (errors never shown).